# Why is 1 =1 not true in this situation?

Tags: vba

This has no value as far as I'm concerned. I discovered this while researching a question.

In VBA:

Given the following: `Dim a As Boolean, b As Boolean, c As Boolean`

The code `a = b = c = 1 = 1`
Assigns a to False.

But `a = b = c = true` assigns a to true.

Can anyone explain why this is so? Obviously `1 = 1` evaluates to true.

As a side note, `a = 1 = 1` will assign a to true as well. Also the behavior is the same using variants instead of Boolean values.

Again I know this has no practical purpose, I'm just curious if anyone can explain the behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression is evaluated left to right because all the operators are of equal precedence.

```
a = b = c = 1 = 1
```

b = c returns True.

True = 1 returns False because True converts to -1 prior to comparison.

False = 1 returns False

```
a = b = c = true
```

b = c returns True

True = true returns True.

Comment: Ah, I would of assumed right to left. But that certainly makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case it is doing comparison from left to right, and not assignment as one would think.

If yuo were to initialise b and c to true

```
b = True
c = True
```

and check the value of a for

```
a = c = 1 = 1
```

you would still find it to be false

So to think about it, it would seem that

```
a = b = c = 1 = 1
```

is effectlive

```
a = (((b = c) = 1) = 1)
```

also, even if you changed the brackets to

```
a = (b = (c = (1 = 1)))
```

it would still be false.

given that b and c is uninitialised (False), the only way you will get a to be true is by changing the statement to

```
a = (b = c) = (1 = 1)
```